# Why is Cast MediaRouteButton always white even on Holo.Light Action-Bar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-theme, chromecast, android-styles

I'm moving from a custom MediaRouteButton to one inside the action-bar but it doesn't display properly.  The button when custom was white which is what I wanted.  However, the button is still white (and barely visible) on the action-bar even though the action-bar is of "Holo.Light" style.  The button should be dark.

The button is created as an XML menu item:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_item_media_route"
    android:title="@string/menu_item_media_route"
    android:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteButton"
    android:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteActionProvider"
    android:showAsAction="always" />
```

My app is of style "@style/AppTheme":

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
</style>
```

My activity of of theme "@style/FullscreenActionbarTheme":

```
<style name="FullscreenActionbarTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/FullscreenActionbar</item>
</style>

<style name="FullscreenActionbar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
</style>
```

I have no custom "ic_media_route_(on|off).png" drawables -- I used to but removed them.

I've tried changing various styles and though the action-bar will turn dark, the cast button is always white.  (As it should be on a dark action bar but not a light one.)

The button is fully functional, just the wrong color.  The "chooser" dialog that appears when I press the button is styled "Holo.Light".

*So why is my cast button colored white on a "Holo.Light" theme as though it was a "Holo" (dark) theme?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from: [Link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediarouter.html)

> Caution: When implementing an activity that provides a media router
> interface you must extend either ActionBarActivity or FragmentActivity
> from the Android Support Library, even if your android:minSdkVersion
> is API 11 or higher.

`ActionBarActivity` has been superseded by `AppCompatActivity`, so you should use that instead.

Support-V7 `MediaRouteButton` depends on this. Look at the `super` call:

```
public MediaRouteButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(MediaRouterThemeHelper.createThemedContext(context), attrs, defStyleAttr);
    ....
    ....
}
```

`MediaRouterThemeHelper.createThemedContext(Context)`:

```
public static Context createThemedContext(Context context) {
    boolean isLightTheme = isLightTheme(context);
    return new ContextThemeWrapper(context, isLightTheme ?
            R.style.Theme_MediaRouter_Light : R.style.Theme_MediaRouter);
}
```

`isLightTheme` is set by resolving `R.attr.isLightTheme` <<== This is a support library attribute. It will not be present when your parent theme is provided by the framework, as is the case with `android:Theme.Holo.Light`.

```
private static boolean isLightTheme(Context context) {
    TypedValue value = new TypedValue();
    return context.getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.isLightTheme, value, true)
            && value.data != 0;
}
```

So, `isLightTheme` is `false` & you get the dark-theme version of `MediaRouteButton` ==> ... always white.

Note that the *Caution* statement implies that your parent theme must be an AppCompat theme - `AppCompatActivity` (or `ActionBarActivity`) can't work with `android:Theme.*`.

**Edit:**

A lot of discussion took place here: [Link](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77662/discussion-between-vikram-and-brian-white)

One can go through the chat-log to read on the approaches tried. In the end, it seems that the media-router support library needs some work to be production-ready. Read more here: [MediaRouteActionProvider connection dialog theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24245926/mediarouteactionprovider-connection-dialog-theme/29080248#29080248).

Comment: My main activity is actually derived from `v4.FragmentActivity` but I guess that was not sufficient.  When I extended `ActionBarActivity` (have not yet advanced to SDK v22) then the button was styled correctly.  However, it's now frelled in a different way because when the action bar shows or hides, the bottom of the screen shows some sort of garbage during the animation (Android 5.1).  Is there some way I can manually set the `R.attr.isLightTheme` and thus work correctly with `v4.FragmentActivity`?

Comment: @BrianWhite Yes, of course, you can toggle `isLightTheme`. You own every attr defined in support-v7. Add `<item name="isLightTheme">true</item>` to the setup you have in the question. The docs aren't up to date on this since (as noted by you) `FragmentActivity` option does not work anymore. _When I extended `ActionBarActivity` (have not yet advanced to SDK v22)..._ Not sure what you mean here <-- You should be using `AppCompatActivity` and that shouldn't have any relation to API level. (contd.)

Comment: @BrianWhite (contd.) Do you mean Android 5.0 here? --> _...some sort of garbage during the animation (Android 5.1). _ I ask because you mentioned that you haven't moved to SDK v22 yet. In any case, I am almost certain that what you are observing is due to the absence of window bg - you request that here: `<item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
`. Since you are overlaying the `ActionBar`, try setting a solid bg (any color with full-blown alpha will do) to your activity's layout's base container.

Comment: @BrianWhite Note that by setting `isLightTheme` under `AppTheme`, you are only fixing a leak. You might need to fix a few more along the way. For example: `MediaRouteChooserDialog` leverages `MediaRouterThemeHelper.getThemeResource(...)` to obtain the drawable resource ID set to `R.attr.mediaRouteOffDrawable`. In your case, the value returned will be 0 because `AppTheme` does not define `R.attr.mediaRouteOffDrawable` (`Theme.AppCompat.*` does). To fix this, look up `mediaRouteOffDrawable` in support-v7's themes file (under `Theme.AppCompat.Light`) and reflect it back to `AppTheme`.

Comment: Whatever my current version of the SDK is, it has ActionBarActivity but not `AppCompatActivity`.  Since I last updated my SDK with the release of API21, I assume it came out along with the release of API22.  I already have the `windowBackground` item assigned `@null`.  When the Actionbar shows, the screen jumps up (with garbage at the bottom) and then slides down.  When the ActionBar hides, the screen slides up revealing garbage at the bottom then jumps down.  Adding the `isLightTheme` item to my theme properly colors the button but the dialogs, which **were** Light, are now dark.

Comment: @BrianWhite Support library update schedules have little correlation with Android system updates. You can choose to update the support library, leaving the SDK version intact. Any way, is there a reason you want to stick with `FragmentActivity`? `AppCompatActivity` extends `FragmentActivity`, and so does `ActionBarActivity`.

Comment: I know.  Updates are generally painful and time-consuming so I do it only when I have good reason.  If it's not broken, don't fix it.  I want to stick with what works and using the real `ActionBar` used by `FragmentActivity` (rather than the support library's action bar) simply works better.  And in this case, the `SupportActionBar` (used by `AppCompatActivity`) is downright broken when it animates on/off the screen.  Any idea why the `isLightTheme` (=true) flag flipped the media-button dialogs from "light" theme to "dark" theme?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77662/discussion-between-vikram-and-brian-white).

Comment: From chat:  The MediaRouter library is apparently broken and the dialogs will appear with a "dark" background even with `isLightTheme` enabled (whether using `FragmentActivity`, `ActionBarActivity`, or `AppCompatActivity`).  That has to be fixed separately, as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24245926/mediarouteactionprovider-connection-dialog-theme/

Comment: @BrianWhite Thanks for the bounty. I'll wait for the next support-library update and check if the issue has been resolved. Will update the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails you can change the color programmatically in onCreate():

```
   ImageButton button = ((ImageButton) toolbar.getChildAt( ... )); // The view index of the button
    button.setColorFilter(Color.BLACK, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

Comment: Given that the bar button changes as the MediaRouter changes connection state, would the filter continue to be applied?